# how to call `localStorage.getItem ` immediately after render

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

first i use `localStorage.setItem` to save a token that i've taken from api and set it as header in my axios

i need to use `local.storage.getItem()` to read the data and then set it as header
so there is another action which sends request ,takes the token and saves it to local storage by `localStorage.setItem()` and replaces the browser history to where i'm calling the action that needs the token ,but it shows 404 error with the only first error which means only at the first time and if i close the page and open it again it works fine 
I'll show the code step by step

here is my code where i want to use the token

```
import axios from 'axios';
const token =  localStorage.getItem('token')//here doesn't get it and shows 404 error from API i refresh the page for second time or after 
export default axios.create({

  headers:{"Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`}
})
```

here is my action where i get the token with diffrent instance of axios which has no `header`

```
export const sendCode = (phone, code) => async dispatch => {
  dispatch({ type: LOADING_STATE })

  const response =
    await loginApi.post(baseurl + "Auth/Checkcode", {
      phone: phone,
      code: code
    },
    )
  dispatch({ type: SEND_CODE, payload: response.data });
  if (response.data.success === true) {
    history.replace('/home')
   localStorage.setItem("token", response.data.obj.token)
  }
```

and finally here is the action that i call it with the instance that has `header`

```
export const getHomeInfo = () => async dispatch => {
  dispatch({type:LOADING_STATE})
 const response = await homeAPI.get(baseurl + "Home/GetList")//homeAPI is the instance that has header

  dispatch({ type: GET_HOME_INFO, payload: response.data })
};
```

Comment: headers:{"Authorization": `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`} try this

Comment: it shows same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import axios from 'axios';
const token =  localStorage.getItem('token')
export default axios.create({

  headers:{"Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`}
})
```

Here, token will be fetch once when the js file is bundled, you have to refetch it each time :

```
import axios from 'axios';


const getHeaders = () => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
  return {"Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`}
}

export default axios.create({
  headers: getHeaders()
})
```

EDIT : The code above does not work since axios.create() is called only once, if you need dynamic headers, you should add an interceptor which will be called before each request :

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create()

axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(
  (config) => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if (token) {
      config.headers.authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
    }
    return config;
  },
  (error) => Promise.reject(error),
);

export default axiosInstance
```

Comment: I added an Edit, I forgot that axios.create is called only once, adding an interceptor allow you to fetch your token at each request

Comment: thank you , where can i read more about axios interceptor or axios.create?

Comment: https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors Here you go

Comment: sorry, I was wondering, Is this a bad practice? as you said `interceptor which will be called before each request ,`  would it be a trouble in the future?

Comment: No it is not, on big apps you'll need interceptors to set, for example, the language required, some authorizations that can differ between requests, or simply for security purpose

Comment: Hi from 2023. I have a problem. When I try to use the `axiosInstance` inside next.js `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps` I face `localStorage is not defined` and I can not send an authorized request to my backend and face `401`. Do you have any idea how I can solve this?